# SQL two counts with three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a SQL Query which reads out of three tables (companies, rights A, rights B). Rights A and B are tables of a m:n relation. I want to count the entries in rights A and B which are connected to companies.

Structure of companies:

`CID | Name | ...`

Structure of Rights A

`RIDe | CID | ...`

Structure of Rights B

`RIDu | CID | ...`

This is my current SQL Statement. I get sometimes the correct values, but sometimes not. I don't know why.

```
SELECT 
    company.*, 
    count(rightsa.RIDe) AS AnzahlE, 
    count(rightsb.RIDu) AS AnzahlU 
FROM company 
LEFT JOIN rightsa ON company.CID = rightsa.CID 
LEFT JOIN rightsb ON company.CID = rightsb.CID 
GROUP BY company.CID ORDER BY company.name;
```

Comment: The Query looks correct .. what do you mean when you say I get sometimes the correct values, but sometimes not.

Comment: @TMNT2014: I can't recognize a rule. Sometimes the value of the second count is the same as the first. But the Question is solved, see M Khalid Junaids answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT` in your count function,so it will count only distinct `rightsa.RIDe` and `rightsb.RIDu` per company

```
SELECT company.*, 
count(DISTINCT rightsa.RIDe) AS AnzahlE, 
count(DISTINCT rightsb.RIDu) AS AnzahlU 
FROM company 
LEFT JOIN rightsa ON company.CID = rightsa.CID 
LEFT JOIN rightsb ON company.CID = rightsb.CID 
GROUP BY company.CID ORDER BY company.name;
```

Comment: One might note that the `distinct` is required here because the left join returns every row from the left table, combined with every matching row in the right table (and null if there was no match). Your two left joins suffer from combinatorial problems: if a company has 3 rows in `rightsa` and 4 rows in `rightsb`, then there are 12 rows in the result set: each `rightsa` row being duplicated once for every matching row in `rightsb`.

Answer (score 1):

`count()` is different than other aggregate functions in that `null` values are *included*: most aggregate functions *exclude* `null` from consideration.

For `select` statements with a `group by` clause, every column in the result set must be, per the SQL standard, one of

- a grouping column or expression,
- an aggregate function,
- a literal,
- an expression involving one or more of the above

Anything else is, at best, undefined behavior per the SQL standard: you are dependent on the vagaries of your particular SQL implementation.

Try something like this:

```
select c.* ,
       coalesce( a.cnt , 0 ) as AnzahlE ,
       coalesce( b.cnt , 0 ) as AnzahlU
from company c
left join ( select CID, count(*) as cnt from rightsa group by CID ) a
left join ( select CID, count(*) as cnt from rightsb group by CID ) b
order by c.name
```

You might also look at using *correlated subselects* that will better express your intent:

```
select c.*
       (select count(*) from rightsa a where a.CID = c.CID) as AnzahlE ,
       (select count(*) from rightsb b where b.CID = c.CID) as AnzahlU
from company c
order by c.Name
```